# open server или ручная настройка?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, openserver

Здраствуйте подскажите что лучше и в чем разница? Скачать Open Server или скачать все ручно MySQL PHP Apache ...,Есть ли разница?

Comment: скачайте OpenServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница в задаче которая стоит.

Если задача улучшить понимание вашего окружения (php, mysql, apache), как это работает, как настраивается и тд и тп, то лучше ставьте самостоятельно и начинайте курить мануалы. Поверьте, результат будет и это в любом случае вам пригодится, если останетесь в IT.

Если стоит задача изучить ЯП (php), научиться работать с бд (mysql), делая запросы из кода и просто через клиент и при этом нет желания отвлекаться на долгие настройки, то тогда ставьте сборку и не парьтесь. Потом когда захотите поковыряться, просто снесите или отключите опенсервер, поставите  на ось пыху, или докер с образом пыхи и будете курить мануалы.

Выбор за вами! Дерзайте.

Comment: Да я на винде временно,через 4-5 мес на Linux Mint перейду(так сказать по обстоятельствам))

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас Windows, не думайте и ставьте OpenServer. Если скачивать всё по отдельности, то место на диске может и сэкономите, хотя, на мой взгляд, экономия сомнительная. А вот настраивать всё в одном приложении будет в первое время куда проще. Кроме того, в OS имеется куча вариантов подключения разных версий веб-сервера, php и разных серверов БД. Всё по отдельности - обычно какая-то одна связка получится.

Answer (score 0):

Разница в понимании.
Поставив всё руками, ты будешь примерно понимать как что работает и как разные части веб-сервера взаимодействуют друг с другом. Со временем сможешь настраивать любые сервера на любых системах

Поставив готовую сборку, ты будешь её рабом, который не понимает смысла своих действий, а только тупо следует инструкции.

Comment: Ну с таким же успехом можно сказать, что все пользователи windows — рабы. ;)

Comment: Этот сайт не про пользователей. А про программистов

Comment: Программисты, которые пользуются видной могут быть названы пользователями винды ИМХО.

Comment: Victor здесь не хватало твое мнение про программистов на винде